# WebView image storage , preloading

Tags: android, image-processing, webview, download, local-storage

I'm trying to display html that looks like this

```
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-9" alt="benzin" src="http://srv100443.hoster-test.ru/Autohelper/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/benzin.jpg" width="250" height="188" />

<h2>Симптомы:</h2>
```

I'm loading my html from string like this

```
private void loadHtmlPage() {
        String htmlString = getHtmlFromAsset();
        if (htmlString != null)
            adviceWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/images/", htmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
        else
            Toast.makeText(this, "No such page", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

**adviceWebView** - is my WebView where i want to show html
So the question is - How to preload images from all my html files(i can get links and download them), but where i need to save them so image with link
`http://srv100443.hoster-test.ru/Autohelper/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/benzin.jpg` was shown from local cashe(or file). And is there anyway to do that without changing link in html?
Can i put files manuly in my IDE to assests? or where they should be placed?